# How to make HTML table renders equally across browsers?

Tags: html, css

I just realized that tables are not rendered equally across browsers.

Let's take a look at this example http://files.fina-indo.com/html-tests/tabletest.html and open it in Firefox and Google Chrome. It will look fine in Firefox but odd in Google Chrome.

is there a way to make it renders equally?
Is using DIV grids is the only solution for this issue?

Note: I am asking this because my Joomla user is a layman, and he does not know anything about HTML and CSS (he only knows about putting the contents). And the WYSIWYG editor inside Joomla does not have an easy way to create DIV grids (Twitter Bootstrap grids). If making the tables looks equally are not an option, is there a TinyMCE plugins or other WYSIWYG editor that can do this?

Here is the HTML I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
    Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>HTML</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="Erwin" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../gamma/templates/shaper_helix_ii/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
      .container {
        width: 940px
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <header>
        <h1>HTML</h1>
      </header>
      <nav>
        <p>
          <a href="/">Home</a>
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </p>
      </nav>

      <div>
        <table border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td colspan="3"><img src="../gamma/images/solutions/GP_Solution_LanSchool.png" alt="" /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td colspan="3"><img src="../gamma/images/solutions/GP_Solution_ROO.png" alt="" /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td colspan="3"><img src="../gamma/images/solutions/GP_Solution_Microsoft.png" alt="" /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"><img src="../gamma/images/solutions/GP_Solution_Eduvision.png" alt="" /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td colspan="3"><img src="../gamma/images/solutions/GP_Solution_KNT_Interactive.png" alt="" /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td colspan="3"><img src="../gamma/images/solutions/GP_Solution_Educo.png" alt="" /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td colspan="3"><img src="../gamma/images/solutions/GP_Solution_MiracleEdu.png" alt="" /></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <footer>
        <p>
          &copy; Copyright  by Erwin
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Firefox screenshot
[image]

Chrome screenshot
[image]

Comment: You should post your HTML and CSS here

Comment: It was my html and css. I thought putting in web is easier because people can look at how it renders in their browsers

Comment: Can you at least add screenshots to show *how* its not rendering the same?

Comment: ^ thank you for inserting the code :D

Comment: I see 2 errors in validator and 1 error in browser console. When you want your tables to render correctly, you should first write them correctly.

Comment: Hmm cleared the errors but not the warning. Thanks for pointing that out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use tables for layout, they are for tabular data, not presentation.**

To satisfy people who say this isn't an answer, if you have a section of yout HTML using an empty row with 15 empty cells to space images correctly, the HTML source needs to be rethought. The only solution for this:

```
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
```

Is to start again and rewrite.

Comment: Yeah I know. Actually I myself uses bootstrap grids for layout :D
But this issue was addressed for those Javascript WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) that is used by Joomla. If only I can force a layman user (my client) to learn some css and html I might not need to ask this :'(

Comment: Not an answer to the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Sometimes the best answer to a question, isn't the answer the asker was expecting. [See also the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This still is not an answer *at all*. It should have been posted as a comment, if at all.

Comment: It is enough. No more debate, I will fill the cells with transparent image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to get tables (and other elements) looking more similar across browsers.

Comment: I revised the html and css. Added normalize.css into it, but it seems tables are really has it owns rendering rules. Still renders differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the problem is related to your css, by adding *{padding:0px; margin:0px;} to your css file at the very top
it will remove ALL paddings and margins on every thing.

Although it will mess up your css, it should make the tables render the same in all browsers.

Once you have established that this is indeed css related then  google for css browser reset hack and implement it. It will attempt to  reset all the non standard browser independant css  settings